# in jetpack compose M3 OutlinedTextField is there a way to move supportingText closer to the text box?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

in Jetpack composes new M3 OutlinedTextField supporting text is placed irritatingly far below the outline of the textfield. Is there a way to move it vertically closer to the outline without wrapping the whole thing in a Column and faking the supportingText?

[image]